# SQL tools leaking over into Visual Studio 2012 tools and has me confused

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bids, sql-server-data-tools

I normally have SSMS on one screen and VS 2012 on the other .. but with the development of SQL tools that are being integrated into VS 2012 the functionality seems to be overlapping..  It seems to me I can do all my common tasks in VS 2012 except for restoring back ups which I need SSMS for.

and There is Sql Server Data Tools.. Which I think is the IDE + SSIS/Reports/SSAS ? And then they removed the Data Compare tool and it is a mystery why.

So my main question is what is the most efficient way to work create .NET web apps.. Use SSMS and VS 2012... or just use VS 2012 sql data tools so I can use VS2012 for most everything which should be more productive ?

The overlap is confusing me and my desire to have things set up in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put (and you should!!!) your tables, stored procs, etc in version control, Visual Studio offers great integration. Otherwise you should use whatever feels more comfortable...

Comment: I use DB projects for that.. But when I am making changes to tables etc.. I am torn which I should be using.. If it does everything but resotre backups I wish they would add that feature then I would never need to open SSMS... I just don't understand MS thinking on these 2 products

Comment: Visual Studio is targeted and developers, SSMS is for DBAs. Most developers would spend most of the time in VS. Most DBAs will not have VS installed at all...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's positioning is that Visual studio is aimed at developers, SSMS is aimed at DBAs. However, as you are finding, there is somewhat of a grey area where those roles overlap. Speaking as a developer rather than a DBA I find that I *can* do everything I need to within Visual Studio however there are still some aspects of SSMS that keep dragging me back. I blogged about my experiences here: [Connected development in SSDT versus SSMS](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/03/19/connected-development-in-ssdt-versus-ssms.aspx)

To answer your question "what is the most efficient way to work create .NET web app" I would suggest you work in Visual Studio. It offers better integration with your .net code by virtue of the fact that your database DDL can live in the same solution as your .net code - and of course there are knock-on benefits from that such as source controlling your database DDL.

If you need to do DBA type "stuff" (e.g. backups/restores/HA configuration) then just pop open SSMS and party on, otherwise stick in Visual Studio.

Hope that helps.